# log4j two loggers with separate files

Tags: java, file, logging, properties, log4j

In my progrm I have 2 loggers and now I have to save them to files, but no files are being created.

```
log4j.rootLogger=arcLog, errorLog, INFO

#ARC-logger properties
log4j.appender.arcLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.arcLog.File=logs/ARC-1Logger.log
log4j.appender.arcLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.arcLog.maxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.arcLog.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.arcLog.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.arcLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.arcLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.appender.arcSLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.arcSLog.File=logs/ARC-Session_Logger.log
log4j.appender.arcSLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.arcSLog.maxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.arcSLog.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.arcSLog.threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.arcSLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.arcSLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.category.arcLog=TRACE, ARC-Logger
log4j.additivity.arcLog=false

log4j.category.errorLog=WARN, ARC-Session_Logger
log4j.additivity.arcSLog=false
```

To get logger I use:

```
loggerF = Logger.getLogger("ARC-Logger");
loggerS = Logger.getLogger("ARC-Session_Logger");
```

Appenders was found cause there was no errors about that, but files are not being created.
Can it be that this project is library that I use in another project together with Hibernate that it also has another logger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things that are not quite right there. Your properties file should look more like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, arcApp, arcSApp

#ARC-logger properties
log4j.appender.arcApp=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.arcApp.File=logs/ARC-1Logger.log
log4j.appender.arcApp.Append=true
log4j.appender.arcApp.maxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.arcApp.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.arcApp.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.arcApp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.arcApp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.appender.arcSApp=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.arcSApp.File=logs/ARC-Session_Logger.log
log4j.appender.arcSApp.Append=true
log4j.appender.arcSApp.maxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.arcSApp.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.arcSApp.threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.arcSApp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.arcSApp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.logger.arcLog=TRACE, arcApp
log4j.additivity.arcLog=false

log4j.logger.arcSLog=WARN, arcSApp
log4j.additivity.arcSLog=false
```

And then you should be able to call your classes like:

```
private static final Logger  loggerF = Logger.getLogger("arcLog");
private static final Logger  loggerS = Logger.getLogger("arcSLog");
```

Few problems I saw in your properties:

- `arcLog` and `arcSLog` are appenders, not loggers, which might lead you to confusion.
- If you want to use `maxFileSize` and `maxBackupIndex` what you need is a `RollingFileAppender`, not a `FileAppender`.
- In the rootLogger property you should first define the level, then the appenders.
- When you actually create the logger is in `log4j.logger.arcLog=TRACE, arcApp`, where you define the level for the logger and the previously declared appender.
- For using the loggers in your java classes you need to call the loggers instead of the appenders.

Comment: It's working but how to create these files under exec file location in logs directory

Comment: That depends on your environment, if you are working in a tomcat application, for instance you could use the property *${catalina.base}* to build your desired relative path.